# Selenium no localiza select list elements, en la pagina web que intento scrapear-

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping, chromedriver

Estoy intentando scrapear, la siguiente pagina: http://www.veracruz.gob.mx/gaceta-oficial/, navegando a través de los select list elements, es decir desde un script de python acceder a la información resultante a especificar determinado año y mes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al intentar esto con el siguiente código, me aparece el siguiente error.

```
import sys
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

'''
    Creando un web driver usando selenium y Chrome versión 101.
'''
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)


driver.get("http://www.veracruz.gob.mx/gaceta-oficial/")
#print(driver.page_source)
#elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

select_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/div/p[1]/select[2]")
select_object = Select(select_element)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revise el resultado de driver.page_source y ni siquiera me aparece el XPATH que estoy usando, intente tambien hacer usar WebDriverWait, por si el problema es que la pagina no había cargado por completo, pero no me funciono. Por ultimo, también intente usar el localizar los select list elements, por medio de su ID y su CLASS_NAME, pero nada.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium no encuentra los elementos HTML que intentas buscar porque esos elementos hacen parte de otra página web.
La página a la que accedes está usando iframe, por lo que, tiene incrustada otra página web con su propio documento HTML.

La solución es visitar la página que esta incrustada

cambia esto:

```py
driver.get("http://www.veracruz.gob.mx/gaceta-oficial/")
```

por esto:

```py
driver.get("http://www.editoraveracruz.gob.mx/gacetas/index_.php")
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimado su error consiste en que la pagina contiene un iframe y selenium para poder interectuar con el iframe, debe añadir un comando antes de hacer alguna acción .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un ejemplo https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/

Luego una vez puedas entrar el iframe podras interactuar con el contenido del mismo.